# Read & Write Application Settings at Runtime in Delphi

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, delphi, winapi

Does Delphi have read/write Application settings at runtime, like others have?

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/settings-page-project-designer?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(ApplicationSettingsOverview)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022).

[image: APP Settings]

Visual Studio C# or VB they have this "FEATURE" But :
PLEASE TELL ME:
Is it true that this feature above can really store data inside Exe At Run time???
Logically, Any [RELEASE] Exe DO NOT accept files to be modified at runtime without losing the EXE image checksum or losing Digitally Sign EXE files and drivers!!!

Comment: Not exactly like that, no. But Delphi does have many classes that can be used to read/write custom app settings in your code, ie `TRegistry` for the Windows Registry, `TIniFile`/`TMemIniFile` for INI files, `TXMLDocument` for XML, `TJSONObject` for JSON, etc. Use whatever suits your needs

Comment: My goal is to find a solution to create const and variables at runtime dynamically and retrieve them the next time when my App run

Comment: Any of the solutions I mentioned in my previous comment can be used to accomplish that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau .  please tell me: is it true that this feature of visual studio store data inside exe app config at runtime while any exe app logically not accept to modify at runtime then keep  image checksum not modiffied or the digitally sign files and drivers !!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. The `.exe` file cannot be modified while it is running. And if it is digitally signed, it cannot be modified AT ALL without invalidating the signature. Configuration settings are never stored in the `.exe` itself. They are stored in external files, or in the Registry.

Comment: The way this question was asked first gives me the horrible idea to abuse DLLs as files to store data: I simply change their ressource content and never need to actually load them. Provided I have write access and checksums aren't required.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not true that the above mentioned feature can store settings in the application executable.

If you would have read [Manage application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022#use-customized-settings-files) documentation of Visual Studio 2022 you would have learned that the above mentioned feature is storing application settings in one of the two files.

- an app.config file, which is created at design time when you create the first application setting
- a user.config file, which is created at runtime when the user who runs the application changes the value of any user setting.

You would have also learned that Application settings can be stored as any data type that is serialized to XML

---

Does Delphi support such or similar feature? As far as I know it doesn't support such feature out of the box.But then again implementing something similar isn't as hard.